# Ubuntu Server Bug Reporting

Tags: server, bug-reporting

Well I made an account on LaunchPad, (eventually broken links in email on mobile because of email in link).

I looked through rgw document
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

It looks geared towards crashes in the GUI. I thought maybe 'Server' bugs are reported elsewhere.

The problem in question is related to DNS lookups locally on a system with Bind running. I'm not exactly sure which component it is.

[Ubuntu 19.04 bind not resolving locally](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1139536/ubuntu-19-04-bind-not-resolving-locally/1139620?noredirect=1#comment1890972_1139620)

Component/Package finding help also seems to be intended to be used with the GUI version.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/FindRightPackage

Is there really no place to report a bug anymore. I just want to press the "New" bug button? Alas it does not seem to exist.

Comment: There is no difference between reporting a Server bug and a Desktop bug. Both get reported to the same bug tracker. However, perhaps you may not be quite ready to report a bug yet: "Something didn't work" is not a useful bug report. A useful bug report must contain enough detail for somebody else to reproduce the behavior upon their system. That usually means narrowing to code in a specific package. A simple test case demonstrating the bug is particularly useful. Bugs that cannot be reliably reproduced cannot be fixed.

Comment: The resolved and systemd-resolved packages have been rather thoroughly tested - your bug might already be reported. Have you checked? It's much easier to subscribe to an existing bug than to create a new bug.

Answer (score 0):

**Alt + F2** and **ubuntu-bug NameOfProgram** can be used to trigger Apport-Error-Report. It will check Integrity and Changes to related Configuration Files, which gives a general Idea wether the Issue is with the Component itself or in the Workings with the surrounding System.

Comment: Okay thanks ubuntu-bug works from the command line on Server. Any idea what package is needed for resolv.conf issues nothing found for systemd-resolve or systemd-resolved?